# Use shell arguments inside GNU Make function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is is possible to use shell arguments inside a makefile function?
e.g.

```
mywords:=hello there neighbour

myrecipe:
    for ((i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)); do \
        this_word=$(word $${i}, $(mywords)); \
    done
```

Except `myrecipe` gives the error `non-numeric first argument to 'word' function: '${i}'. Stop`

Comment: You're trying to use a *Make* function inside a *shell* function, and no, it won't work. Is this just exploration, or are you actually trying to do something?

Comment: No, any shell arguments are expanded after the makefile function is done. However, what you present is the shell function for. You can the line with `for this_word in $mywords; do \ ` and you'll have shell variable `this_word` set each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that *make* first expands the entire recipe (yes, that's all of the recipe lines) before ever doing anything with the shell.
Only after this full expansion does *make* then look for individual recipe lines, running each one in turn.

Thus *make* behaves sensibly when you have a macro that expands to more than one line.

It also hints that you should use *make* functionality wherever possible.

```
mywords := hello there neighbour

define mkcommand
    echo $1
    something $1
endef

myrecipe:
    $(foreach _,${mywords},$(call mkcommand,$_))
```

Now, when you ask *make* to build *myrecipe*,
*make* sees something like:

```
myrecipe:
    echo hello
    something hello
    echo there
    something there
    ⋮
```

IMHO it's nearly always a mistake if you find yourself writing shell loops in a makefile.

Comment: I agree with your description of `make`'s operation, but not necessarily with your recommendation.  If one is interested in writing portable (that is, not GNU-specific) makefiles, then `make` itself sometimes doesn't provide what you need.  Moreover, even when GNU `make` is targeted, I find it much clearer to reserve `make` functions for top-scope code, and to use only shell code in recipes.  One may be able to avoid looping *at all*, but if a loop must appear in a recipe then I would prefer it to be expressed in shell language.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Doing it in _make_ invariably produces cleaner build files in my experience, covers more corner cases, and is easier to refactor. Admittedly I know _make_ quite well. For example, most loops do not check for non-zero exit codes properly. Parallel builds also start working, and we all have more than one CPU nowadays (your makefile is broken if it doesn't work when building in parallel). Shell loops are usually a sign that the author isn't familiar with _make_. Similar problems accrue when `$(shell … )` is overused. YMMV applies of course.